# How to get rid of the "Can I help" duck?

Tags: discussion

sharepoint.stackexchange.com now has a "duck". It's either:
 - spyware
 - a bad April Fools joke
 - or just an annoying bad idea.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mods - can you please migrate this question to the [SP Meta](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/)

@Mike - Its April fools joke part of SO tradition.

Last year it was DDA protocol - [Stack Overflow Introduces Dance Dance Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU)

This quack is based on cookies.

You can run the below jQuery snippet to set the cookie value to 1 which will disable the duck.

```
$(".quackoverflow").hide() && $.cookie("quack",1,{"path":"/","expires":3})
```

This cookie is site specific and will haunt you on the SO network.

[image]

References - [Quack Overflow tagged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quack-overflow)

[What the duck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365371/862892)

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: I am sure the Duck solved more issues than some AI based chat bots ;)